# SVN: Pull latest revision number only

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to run svn command that will be used in grunt shell that will allow me to pull only the latest revision number from HEAD. So when I do `svn log -r HEAD` it shows me all of the information for the latest. From that, I only need the revision number so I can add it to my app for developers to see what the last commit was. Is there a way to run a command to only get the latest revision number only?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `info` command:

```
$ svn info -r HEAD $REPO/trunk/proj
Path: trunk/project
URL: http://svn.vegicorp.net/repo/trunk
Relative URL: ^/trunk/proj
Repository Root: http://svn.vegicorp.net/repo
Repository UUID: dfa478bd-130c-4e4c-9ce8-d3cdc67c4965
Revision: 13406
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: bob
Last Changed Rev: 13406
Last Changed Date: 2015-04-08 16:19:03 -0400 (Wed, 08 Apr 2015)
```

You can use `awk` or `sed` to pull out the data you want. The *Revision* is the revision of the whole repository. The *Last Changed Rev* is the last revision where something was changed on this particular URL. There's also a XML output by using `--xml`. If you can parse XML, that may make it easier to get the data you want.